# Adapter Write Protect for Hard Disk

Tags: voltage-regulator

I need to protect hard disk (sata) for read-only, like SD-card have write protect.

Cable sata have channel A & B. Can i cut A or B??? Or any other way?

Help me please!

Thank everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SD card read-only switch is a software protection, not hardware protection (i.e. some devices simply ignore the switch or may use it for different purposes).

SATA signals can't be cut because the device would not work at all.

Answering to your question: you can not make your hard drive read-only just by cutting SATA cable. You have to do it in software or some kind of translating hardware. I think software is easier.

As another approach, if you just need to do some kind of testings, then you can image your hard drive and run it under some emulator making your image read only.

Comment: i need hardware to protect my hard disk.

i see 1 hardware http://www.amazon.com/CoolGear%C2%AE-SATA-Adapter-Write-Protect-Selection/dp/B005C55OYA

can you help me?

Comment: @tungcholon - Haven't you just answered your own question?

Answer (score 0):

A lot more information is needed, like what operating system is accessing the drive.

Assuming Unix, it is very easy to mount a drive read-only:

```
mount -r /dev/diskXsY /path/to/mount/point
```

Making the actual drive completely read-only would require hardware support from the manufacturer and will likely cause other issues. Modern OS still wants to write metadata even if the files are read-only.